# XRC error when trying to access PostgreSQL view properties

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have strange problem, when trying to access PostgreSQL view properties through PgAdmin III:

```
Error: XRC error: 197: invalid row index 1: must be less than 1
```

After this error is displayed, I am able to open the dialog.

I tried to Google it to no avail. I am using PostgreSQL 9.3.5 (on Debian 7) and PGAdmin III 1.20.

Comment: Also getting this error on Postgresql 9.4.1, PGAdmin 3 1.20, Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I get this since upgrading from pgAdmin 1.18 to pgAdmin 1.20 (PGSQL 9.3 to PGSQL 9.4)